# Как сделать структуры БД для автомобильных товаров

Tags: mysql, laravel

Дано:

- Марка
- Модель (при выборе марки)
- Поколение (при выборе модели)
- Комплектация (при выборе поколения)
- Кузов (при выборе модели)
- Двигатель (при выборе кузова)

(У каждого пункта есть своя таблица, то есть есть таблица marka - в ней все марки автомобилей, есть таблица model - в ней все модели автомобилей и т.д.)

Для товара есть только одно обязательное значение - Модель, остальные по выбору

Для товара можно указать несколько автомобилей

В голове два варианта реализации:

**1**. Создаем пять столбиков (Модель, Поколение, Комплектация, Кузов, Двигатель) для каждого столбика тип JSON, в нем храним выбранные данные (id)

Пример получаемой таблицы

*prods*

```
id |      name       | model | pokolenie | komplektaciya | kuzov | dvigatel
 1 | Название товара | {1,2} |  {1,2,3}  |  {1,2,3,4,5}  |  {1}  | {1,2,3,4}
```

**2**. Делаем связи, создаем 5 связующих таблиц

Например создаем таблицу model и pokolenie

*model*

```
id | model_id | prod_id
 1 |     1    |    1
 2 |     2    |    1
```

*pokolenie*

```
id | pokolenie_id | prod_id
 1 |        1     |    1
 2 |        2     |    1
 3 |        3     |    1
```

И таблица с товаром

*prods*

```
id |      name
 1 | Название товара
```

Мне больше нравится первый вариант, из-за простоты, меньше запросов в БД и меньше объема записей, ориентировочное кол-во товаров >5 мл, у каждого товара может быть с десяток выбранных значений (модель, поколение, комплектация, кузов, двигатель)

Как правильно сделать структуры?

Answer (score 0):

в первом варианте, я так понимаю, вы храните id в json`ах, в таком случае, удобство внесения данных нивелируется сложностью выборок и поддержанием консистентных данных (что делать, если какая - либо модель будет удалена?), второй вариант, на мой взгляд более практичен, со всеми связующими таблицами. По поводу кол-ва транзакций, сомневаюсь что их будет гораздо меньше в первом случае, так как информацию по моделям, кузовам, двигателям и т.д. вы как будете получать?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, если я правильно понимаю связи, то делаем один запрос - получение информации о товаре (название товара), затем делаем 5 связующих запросов на получение ид и потом делаем запросы по полученным id из связующих таблиц и получаем название (модель, поколение)?